# How to fix: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to install Arfooo on my host.

First I got a warning about:

```
Deprecated: mysql_connect()
```

After fixing that, now I get this error:

```
function executeQueryWithPrefix($sql, $tablesPrefix)
{
    $sql = str_replace("CREATE TABLE `", "CREATE TABLE `" . $tablesPrefix, $sql);
    $sql = str_replace("INTO `", "INTO `" . $tablesPrefix, $sql);

    //echo $sql."<br>";

    return mysqli_query($sql);
}

function dbConnect($server, $user, $pass, $dbName)
{

    /* install database with prefixed tables */

    mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $user, $pass, $dbName);
    //mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass) or die('could not connect to mysql');;

    mysqli_query($dbName, 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `table`');
    //mysql_query('create database IF NOT EXISTS ' . $dbName);

    mysqli_select_db($dbName) or die('could not select database');
}
```

Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: `$conn =  mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $user, $pass, $dbName);` and then `mysqli_query($conn, 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `table`');`

Comment: "expects 1 parameter to be mysqli" means you have to pass mysqli object in mysqli_query, refer what @Anant has shown

Comment: Also in first function what you are doing that is completely in-understandable

Comment: @Anant, well, I'm not good in PHP at all. I'm just trying to install arfoo.net

Comment: @Anant now I get another error: Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /public_html/uooro.com/install/dbfunctions.php on line 36
could not select database

Comment: @Anant, Thanks! I fixed second warning by adding $conn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$link = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $user, $pass, $dbName);

mysqli_query($link, 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `table`');
```

With mysqli you need to save the connection in variable and provide that for every time you use mysqli.

EDIT: generally: You need to provide the connection for every mysqli-related function you use.

Comment: Thanks! Now I get another error: Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /public_html/uooro.com/install/dbfunctions.php on line 36 could not select database

Comment: Thanks! I fixed second warning by adding $conn

Comment: @Kardo generally: You need to provide the connection for every mysqli-related function you use.